# With statement being ignored in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have two functions. The first creates a new CSV file (from an existing CSV). The second appends the same data to the new CSV, but in a slightly different order of the rows.

When I run this together all in one file the first function works but the second does not. However when I tried putting the second function in a separate file then calling it in the first script, it did work, albeit I had to enter the input twice.

What do I need to change to get the second function to run properly?

```
import csv
export = raw_input('>')
new_file = raw_input('>')

ynabfile = open(export, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ynabfile)

def create_file():
    with open(new_file, 'wb') as result:
        writer = csv.writer(result)
        for r in reader:
            writer.writerow((r[3], r[5], r[6],r[7], r[7],
                r[8],r[8],r[9],r[10]))

def append():
    with open(new_file, 'ab') as result2:
        writer2 = csv.writer(result2)
        for i in reader:
            writer.writerow((r[3], r[5], r[6], r[7], r[7],
                r[8], r[8], r[10], r[9]))

create_file()

append()
```

I'm new to Python and programming in general, so if there is an all around better way to do this, I'm all ears.

Comment: not a good idea to use `append` as function name .

Comment: After the reader is iterated through the first time, it doesn't reset itself before the next time it's used. You need to create a new reader  every time it's used, or better yet, store the results in a list using something like `reader = [line for line in csv.reader(ynabfile)]` instead.

Comment: What exactly are the data you want to append to the new file? It looks like maybe it's just another copy of the `ynabfile`...

Comment: @martineaue it's an import file for journal entries (I'm an accountant by day) so most columns are the same. The last two columns have to be reversed - credits and debits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv reader has already read the entire file pointed to by `ynabfile`, so on the second call (or any subsequent calls) to either `create_file` or `append` will not be able to fetch any more data using the reader until the file pointer is sent back to the beginning.  In your case, a quick fix would be this:

```
create_file()
ynabfile.seek(0)
append()
```

I recommend restructuring your code a bit to avoid pitfalls like this.  A few recommendations:

- Read all the contents in `ynabfile` into another list instead, if you can fit the entirety of the file into memory
- Have `create_file` and `append` take parameter of input and output file names
- Alternatively, have those two functions take the file pointer (`ynabfile` in this case), and ensure that it is seeked to the beginning then create a new `csv.reader` instance using that.